# Table TTL on SummingMergeTree

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE metric (                                                                                           
    cid UInt32,
    sid UInt32,
    sub String,
    cc UInt32,
    ic UInt32,
    cmc UInt32,
    acc UInt32,
    ts_update DATETIME DEFAULT now()
) ENGINE = SummingMergeTree((cc, ic, cmc, acc)) 
PARTITION BY (cid, sid, sub) 
ORDER BY tuple() 
TTL ts_update + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

I am calling

```sql
INSERT INTO metric (cid, sid, sub, cc, ic, cmc, acc, ts_update) 
VALUES (1000, 2000, 'test', 10, 1, 30, 40, now())
```

every 10 seconds for 5 minutes (TTL).

At the end of 5 minutes the entire row will be deleted since `ts_update` field is not updated every time I insert in summing merge tree.

All I want to do is, if no row is inserted to partition `(cid, sid, sub)` in 5 minutes, delete the row but if any insertion is made, update the TTL as new `ts_update` + 5 minutes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: could you try to declare *ts_update* as *Int32 DEFAULT 0*, TTL as *TTL toDateTime(ts_update) + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE* and in INSERT always pass *1* instead on *now()*?

Comment: create table statment fails with:
`Code: 450. DB::Exception: Received from clickhouse-server:9000. DB::Exception: TTL expression should use at least one Date or DateTime column. `
 when I do what @vladimir said

Answer (score 3):

```sql
CREATE TABLE metric (                                                                                           
    cid UInt32,
    sid UInt32,
    sub String,
    cc  SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64),
    ic  SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64),
    cmc SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64),
    acc SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64),
    ts_update SimpleAggregateFunction(max, DateTime) DEFAULT now()
) ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (cid, sid, sub)
TTL ts_update + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

Though it will not work. TTL removes old rows before SUMS have calculated. There is no solution.

Comment: Thing I wanted to achieve should actually be kinda trivial. It is interesting that there is no solution. Thanks anyway